# Loop through XML to return all nodes

Tags: sql, xml, t-sql, nodes

I have the following xml

```
<ListOrderItemsResult>
  <OrderItems>
    <OrderItem>
      <OrderItemId>01691605007219</OrderItemId>
      <GiftWrapPrice>
        <Amount>0.00</Amount>
        <CurrencyCode>GBP</CurrencyCode>
      </GiftWrapPrice>
      <QuantityOrdered>1</QuantityOrdered>
      <GiftWrapTax>
        <Amount>0.00</Amount>
        <CurrencyCode>GBP</CurrencyCode>
      </GiftWrapTax>
      <SellerSKU>WB0812005-2</SellerSKU>
      <Title>Solid Oak Silk Lined Wooden Gift Box for Whisky, Wine and Champagne (2 Pack)</Title>
      <ShippingTax>
        <Amount>0.00</Amount>
        <CurrencyCode>GBP</CurrencyCode>
      </ShippingTax>
      <ShippingPrice>
        <Amount>0.99</Amount>
        <CurrencyCode>GBP</CurrencyCode>
      </ShippingPrice>
      <ItemTax>
        <Amount>0.00</Amount>
        <CurrencyCode>GBP</CurrencyCode>
      </ItemTax>
      <ItemPrice>
        <Amount>43.99</Amount>
        <CurrencyCode>GBP</CurrencyCode>
      </ItemPrice>
      <PromotionDiscount>
        <Amount>0.00</Amount>
        <CurrencyCode>GBP</CurrencyCode>
      </PromotionDiscount>
      <ASIN>B00911O3IY</ASIN>
      <ConditionId>New</ConditionId>
      <QuantityShipped>1</QuantityShipped>
      <ConditionSubtypeId>New</ConditionSubtypeId>
      <ConditionNote>Free Postage and Packaging / Brand New / Original Packaging / Dispatched from UK Warehouse by Royal Mail or Parcelforce</ConditionNote>
      <ShippingDiscount>
        <Amount>0.00</Amount>
        <CurrencyCode>GBP</CurrencyCode>
      </ShippingDiscount>
    </OrderItem>
    <OrderItem>
      <OrderItemId>14086955545403</OrderItemId>
      <GiftWrapPrice>
        <Amount>0.00</Amount>
        <CurrencyCode>GBP</CurrencyCode>
      </GiftWrapPrice>
      <QuantityOrdered>1</QuantityOrdered>
      <GiftWrapTax>
        <Amount>0.00</Amount>
        <CurrencyCode>GBP</CurrencyCode>
      </GiftWrapTax>
      <SellerSKU>WB0812005-2</SellerSKU>
      <Title>Solid Oak Silk Lined Wooden Gift Box for Whisky, Wine and Champagne (2 Pack)</Title>
      <ShippingTax>
        <Amount>0.00</Amount>
        <CurrencyCode>GBP</CurrencyCode>
      </ShippingTax>
      <ShippingPrice>
        <Amount>1.00</Amount>
        <CurrencyCode>GBP</CurrencyCode>
      </ShippingPrice>
      <ItemTax>
        <Amount>0.00</Amount>
        <CurrencyCode>GBP</CurrencyCode>
      </ItemTax>
      <ItemPrice>
        <Amount>43.99</Amount>
        <CurrencyCode>GBP</CurrencyCode>
      </ItemPrice>
      <PromotionDiscount>
        <Amount>0.00</Amount>
        <CurrencyCode>GBP</CurrencyCode>
      </PromotionDiscount>
      <ASIN>B00911O3IY</ASIN>
      <ConditionId>New</ConditionId>
      <QuantityShipped>1</QuantityShipped>
      <ConditionSubtypeId>New</ConditionSubtypeId>
      <ConditionNote>Free Postage and Packaging / Brand New / Original Packaging / Dispatched from UK Warehouse by Royal Mail or Parcelforce</ConditionNote>
      <ShippingDiscount>
        <Amount>0.00</Amount>
        <CurrencyCode>GBP</CurrencyCode>
      </ShippingDiscount>
    </OrderItem>
    <OrderItem>
      <OrderItemId>15068544085995</OrderItemId>
      <GiftWrapPrice>
        <Amount>0.00</Amount>
        <CurrencyCode>GBP</CurrencyCode>
      </GiftWrapPrice>
      <QuantityOrdered>1</QuantityOrdered>
      <GiftWrapTax>
        <Amount>0.00</Amount>
        <CurrencyCode>GBP</CurrencyCode>
      </GiftWrapTax>
      <SellerSKU>WB0812005-2</SellerSKU>
      <Title>Solid Oak Silk Lined Wooden Gift Box for Whisky, Wine and Champagne (2 Pack)</Title>
      <ShippingTax>
        <Amount>0.00</Amount>
        <CurrencyCode>GBP</CurrencyCode>
      </ShippingTax>
      <ShippingPrice>
        <Amount>1.00</Amount>
        <CurrencyCode>GBP</CurrencyCode>
      </ShippingPrice>
      <ItemTax>
        <Amount>0.00</Amount>
        <CurrencyCode>GBP</CurrencyCode>
      </ItemTax>
      <ItemPrice>
        <Amount>43.99</Amount>
        <CurrencyCode>GBP</CurrencyCode>
      </ItemPrice>
      <PromotionDiscount>
        <Amount>0.00</Amount>
        <CurrencyCode>GBP</CurrencyCode>
      </PromotionDiscount>
      <ASIN>B00911O3IY</ASIN>
      <ConditionId>New</ConditionId>
      <QuantityShipped>1</QuantityShipped>
      <ConditionSubtypeId>New</ConditionSubtypeId>
      <ConditionNote>Free Postage and Packaging / Brand New / Original Packaging / Dispatched from UK Warehouse by Royal Mail or Parcelforce</ConditionNote>
      <ShippingDiscount>
        <Amount>0.00</Amount>
        <CurrencyCode>GBP</CurrencyCode>
      </ShippingDiscount>
    </OrderItem>
</ListOrderItemsResult>
```

I want to select each  and have come up with the following code which works but only retrieves the first item and the qty

```
SELECT  doc.value('(OrderItems/OrderItem/OrderItemId)[1]','nvarchar(255)') AS 'OrderItemId' ,doc.value('(OrderItems/OrderItem/QuantityOrdered)[1]', 'int') AS 'QuantityOrdered' 
FROM    @xml.nodes('/ListOrderItemsResult') AS ref ( doc )
```

Can anyone provide a solution that will return all the items i.e. the 3 items in the XML. I an aware it has something to do with the [1] instance but cannot work out how to return all items.

Comment: Did you try removing the `[1]`?

Comment: Yes. This generates the following error: XQuery [value()]: 'value()' requires a singleton (or empty sequence), found operand of type 'xdt:untypedAtomic *'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT  doc.value('./OrderItemId[1]/text()[1]','nvarchar(255)') AS 'OrderItemId',
        doc.value('./QuantityOrdered[1]/text()[1]', 'int') AS 'QuantityOrdered' 
FROM    @xml.nodes('/ListOrderItemsResult/OrderItems/*') AS ref ( doc )
```